# Problems using scanner to get url content to a string in Android

Tags: android, string, url, webview

I'm trying to copy url contents with user info.
First, the user log in and then the page show the user info. I want to copy that info to a String.
I am using this:

```
try {
    variable1 = new Scanner(new URL("https://example.com/hello").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
}catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("The URL is not valid.");
}catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("The URL is not valid.");
}
```

But I am getting the content in the login page...(as the user never logged in).

Answer (score 0):

I thing maybe missing the cookie id in the request header. The cookie id is in the header of the response after the login request finished.